# Show this induced metric is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

> Let $d$ be a metric on $X$ and $(X,d)$ a non-compact metric space i.e. $X = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$
>   For $x,y \in X$ define
>   $$
> \tilde{d}(x,y)
> := \begin{cases}
> d(x,y), & \text{if }d(x,y) < 1, \\
> 1,      & \text{else.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $\tilde{d}$ is metric on $X$.

**My attempts**

Because $d$ is a metric, $\tilde{d}(x,y) \ge 0$ for all $x,y \in X$.
If $x = y$, we have $d(x,y) = 0 < 1$ and therefore $\tilde{d}(x,y) = 0$
If $\tilde{d}(x,y) = 0 \neq 1$, we have $\tilde{d}(x,y) = d(x,y) = 0$ and therefore somit $x = y$.

This metric is trivially symmetric, since $d$ is.

Let $x,y,z \in X$.

*Case 1: $d(x,z) < 1$.*
Then we have
            $$
    \tilde{d}(x,z)
    = d(x,z)
    \le d(x,y) + d(y,z).
   $$

*Case 2: $d(x,z) \ge 1$.*
Then, we have
            $$
    1
    = \tilde{d}(x,z)
    \le d(x,z)
    \le d(x,y) + d(y,z).
   $$

But I know know how to continue from here, I know that we have $\tilde{d}(x,y) \le d(x,y)$ für alle $x,y \in X$, but I don't know how to use it.

Is my approach for the positive definiteness and symmetry correct? How can I prove the triangle inequality?

Comment: yes symmetry and positive definite is correct. For the triangle inequality you can again distinguish between the cases $d(x,y)\leq 1$ and $d(x,y)>1$ and the same for $d(y,z)$.

Comment: Your first case for the inequality is correct, for case 2 assuming the inequality does not hold true leads to a fairly simple contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of triangle inequality: let $x,y,z \in X$. If $d(x,z) \geq 1$ then $\tilde {d} (x,z) =1$ so $\tilde {d} (x,y)\leq 1 \leq \tilde {d} (x,z)+\tilde {d} (y,z)$. Similarly, if $d(y,z) \geq 1$ then $\tilde{d}(x,y) \leq \tilde {d} (x,z)+\tilde {d} (y,z)$. Finally if $d(x,z) < 1$ and $d(y,z) < 1$ the $\tilde {d} (x,y) \leq d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z) = \tilde {d} (x,z)+\tilde {d} (y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

For all $x \in X$ and every $r > 0$, we have $B(x,r) \subset \bar B(x,r)$, where $\bar B(x,r)$ is the ball with the $\bar d$ metric.

For some positive $s < \min(r,1)$ we have $\bar B(x,s) \subset B(x,r)$, which suffices to show equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one could rewrite the metric as
$$
\tilde{d}(x,y)
:= \min(1, d(x,y)).
$$
Then, the triangle inequality becomes [easy to verify](http://www.math.kit.edu/iana1/lehre/funcana2012w/media/es2sol.pdf):
\begin{align}
\tilde{d}(x,z)
& = \min(1, d(x,z))
\le \min(1, d(x,y) + d(y,z)) \\
& \le \min(1, d(x,y)) + \min(1,d(y,z))
= \tilde{d}(x,y) + \tilde{d}(y,z).
\end{align}